# Laravel with ReactJS - Sass not being loaded

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have built my components and imported them into the Laravel framework. I have set react as preset and the App loads. The Sass files are in each folder that has a component eg.

```
\ComponentX
--ComponentX.js
--ComponentX.module.scss
```

The files load fine but there is no css being added.

I have done `npm install sass-node` - that is all so far.

I tried to place sass file in the 'sass' folder that is given to us when Laravel is installed but nothing happens, Is there further configuration required?

WEBPACKMIX

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.browserSync('localhost:8000');
```

I am importing the sass into my components

```
import styles from './App.module.scss';
```

I have one view 'home.blade.php', which I point the script to the js resource and have an id for App.js to pin to.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link href="{{asset('js/sass/app.scss')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is in your `webpack.mix.js`?

Comment: Hi updated in question. Thank you - Do i need to add the url for each sass file in each component/element?

Comment: Are you importing the sass in your components? Or are you including the compiled css in your (Laravel) views?

Comment: import styles from './App.module.scss'; - in the component

Comment: updated the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well you will need to configure a sass loader if you're importing the sass in your React components. You can pass your own webpack config to laravel mix: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#custom-webpack-configuration